# Buddhas after Bhadra Kalpa

Tags: sutras, buddhas

I have seen in certain books that there is gonna be a lot of buddha shunya kalpas after the bhadra kalpa. Also it has stated about names of 10 Buddhas after the Bhadra kalpa.

Is there a sutra source for these facts? Where can i find them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no mention on the future buddhas except Metteyya buddha in the pali canon. However, there's a book, *[Dasabodhisattuppattikatha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dasabodhisattuppattikatha)* which was written much later than the compilation of the pali cannon, possibly influenced by Mahayana bodhisattva ideals. Here's a list of the 10 buddhas in that book.

1. Metteyya
2. Rāma
3. Dhammarāja
4. Abhibhū
5. Dīghasonī
6. Cankī
7. Subha
8. Todeyya
9. Tissa
10. Sumangala

*Source: https://what-buddha-said.net/drops/III/The_10_Future_Buddhas.htm*